# Remote desktop client to connect to Linux from Vista x64

Tags: vista64, opensuse

I am looking at connecting to a openSuse 11.1 Beta 3 virtual machine from my Vista 64-bit development workstation. I found UltraVNC Viewer to be the only option for this purpose. Is there any other clients that I can use to connect from Vista to openSuse/other Linux installs?

Note: Bandwidth is not a worry, the connection will be using a Gigabit network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about Vista but I have successfully used [X-Ming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming) on Windows XP to talk to a Debian box.

Comment: Adam,

I was away on holidays, sorry about the delay in marking your reply as the best! Yes, X-Ming is the solution I really liked and using it now. By the way, your blog is very informative and useful.

Cheers,
indy

Answer (score 1):

I will double Adam's suggestion to use XMing. You can also enable X11-Forwarding in SSH and use, say, PuTTy, to open up different X applications running on the SUSE box (this, if I remember correctly, requires some sort of a X server to be running on the Windows box, and for which, I have been using [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).

That aside, I've used [tightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) before to export X displays on Linux boxes over to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully used both VNC (with UltraVNC) and XMing to access GUI sessions from Windows on a Linux box. You can find a [detailed tutorial about setting up Xming on my blog](http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2007/08/setting-up-xming-or-rdp-equivalent-for.html). You could also try [xrdp](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/) if you for some reason need to use the RDP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I have been happily using [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com) NxClient on windows, conecting to nxServer on a suse linux box. The lag is minimal, feels very fast. Sessions can be only suspended, which adds to the feeling of speed.